# How to manage Ingress which routes to different helm subcharts?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm

I have the following applications (deployed with k8s) as helm subcharts:

- Prometheus
- Grafana
- airflow-webserver
- custom-application
- custom-api
- custom-webapp

This is nested under an umbrella chart.

The custom-webapp is the main application and should be routed to at mywebsite.com

I'm wondering how do I set up my ingress so that:

- `mywebsite.com` routes to `custom-webapp:5000`
- `mywebsite.com/services/app` routes to `custom-application:5000`
- `mywebsite.com/api/` routes to `custom-api:5000`
- `mywebsite.com/services/airflow` routes to `airflow:8080`
- `mywebsite.com/services/prometheus` routes to `prometheus:9090`
- `mywebsite.com/services/grafana` routes to `grafana:3000`

Do I have 1 main ingress at the umbrella chart which routes to services exposed through subcharts? (the one i'm leaning most towards)
OR
Do I have multiple ingresses for each application ? In this case how do I tie them together?

This is hosted on GKE, and I'd kinda prefer to not pay for 1 ingress per application.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure a collection of [rules](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#ingress-rules) that will define which connections reach which services.
You can aggregate several Ingress rules into a single Ingress definition.

If you are using Kubernetes 1.6+ you can check out this [documentation](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/nginx-ingress) regarding an nginx-ingress deployment on a Kubernetes cluster using the Helm package manager.